# When I use prepareForSegue to pass value to the aim controller, there are some problems

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

Firstly, I use storyboard to create two uiviewcontroller: *firstviewcontroller* and *secondviewcontroller*. And using xcode to embed a *uinavigationcontroller* into *secondviewcontroller***(editor --> embed in --> navigation controller)**. Then, I also want to use segue to pass value from first to second. there is the code:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"passValue"])
    {
        secondViewController *saveViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        [saveViewController setValue:data forKey:@"data"];
    }
}
```

But there will report error, the log is:
***Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key data.'***

However, when I delete the navigation controller that I use Xcode to insert it and define the navigation bar by code, this problem will disappear. I guess the reason is the real destinationViewController is *navigationcontroller* instead of *secondviewcontroller*. So if I want to reserve the navigation controller that is embedded by Xcode, how can fix this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're right, *destinationViewController* will be a *UINavigationController* you have *secondViewController* embeded in. Maybe try that:

```
secondViewController *saveViewController = [[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];
```